# Работа с командной строкой

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, библиотеки

в результате парсинга электронных писем возникла загвоздка, мой парсер

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import setuptools

name: str = input ("Введите имя входящего файла: ")
f = open (name, "r")  # открываем файл
lines = f.readlines ()  # читаем его построчно
t1 = lines [6]
t2 = lines [-5]
t3 = lines [-6]
for line in lines:
    if line.find ('Информирование') != -1:  # то что ищем
        t5 = line [0:40]  # определяет глубину
        print (t5)  # выводим на экран проверяем
        break
#--------
for line in lines:
    if line.find ('НА НР') != -1:  # то что ищем
        t4 = line [7:40]  # определяет глубину
        print (t4)  # выводим на экран проверяем
        break
name1: str = input ("Введите имя исходящего файла: ")
f = open (name1, "w+")
# f.write(str(t1 + "\n" +  t2))
f.write ('реквизит верхний// ' + str (t1))
f.write ('реквизит нижний// ' + str (t2))
f.write ('дата// ' + str (t3))
f.write ('\nнанр// ' + str (t4))
f.write ('\n// ' + str (t5))
f.close ()
```

закрывает окно после выполнения задачи

прошу помочь справиться с следующими задачами

1. **не закрывать окно командной строки при завершении задачи**
2. **писать успешность выполнения задач**и ("Задача выполнена"/"Задача не выполнена")
3. **После Успешного завершения задачи в командную строку выводить сформированный файл** (тут важна динамика), так как выходной файл как видно из кода обзывается мной или оператором как угодно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В работе с `Word` я не силён, но вроде есть разные библиотеки. Боюсь только нет универсальных библиотек, для каждого формата надо будет искать свой подход. Вот например библиотека для [DOCX](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

> не закрывать окно командной строки при завершении задачи

Элементарно - добавьте `input` в конце скрипта:

```
input('Нажмите Ввод для продолжения')
```

> писать успешность выполнения задачи ("Задача выполнена"/"Задача не
> выполнена")

Каковы критерии успешности? Заведите некий `success_flag = True` и сбрасывайте его в случае ошибок. В конце проверяйте и пишите соответствующее сообщение (можно написать через простой `if`, но такая форма записи короче):

```
print(("Задача выполнена","Задача не выполнена")[1-success_flag])
```

> После Успешного завершения задачи в командную строку выводить
> сформированный файл

Ну, напечатайте `name1` через `print`. Или вы хотите, чтобы файл автоматически запустился на просмотр? Это можно сделать через `subprocess`, поищите тут поиском, примеров полно.